# Protractor: Failure during waitForPromise: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor, ui-automation

Protractor regression test specs were working fine till last week, then out of nowhere when I run the same specs now protractor takes a lot of time to interact with the webelements like (`getText()` from dropDown,context menu so on) in the application even there were no changes in code. It throws this error:

> "Failure during waitForPromise: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 60 seconds
>     (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
>   [11:24:57] E/plugins -          ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds"

Tried using this option in Onprepare function `-browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);`
After this step getting the same error which ends with "result was not received in 60 seconds"

Tried these below tags as well but all the pages in the application are angular only. When i use any of the below tags could able to resolve the above issue but other test cases are failing which are supposed to wait for angular.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

I can enable and disable these tags before and after the particular step, but I have 1000+ test cases and i have to invest a lot of time to find where and all it is happening , moreover these tests were working well for more then 8 months and why failing now?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I suspect that Driver version and chrome version incompatibility could be the reason for your problem. Since chrome driver 2.41 supports v67-69 and you are using v75. We also observed that there are many evident instances of this. I would suggest first make sure that drive and chrome browser compatibility before running any test case. You can update the webdriver-manager to get the right version of chrome driver

Comment: Hi Nitin, Tried updating the chromedriver still i am getting this below error:"Fail:  protractor-testability-plugin Plugin Tests
[11:09:44] E/plugins -          Failure during waitForPromise: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
[11:09:44] E/plugins -ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
(Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.90)".. Any suggestion?

Comment: I am using this selenium stand alone "selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar"

Comment: Protractor default supported browsers are chrome and firefox so you can use directConnect property for running chrome directly. It's difficult to comment here but you can try first run sample script file of protractor to verify that there is no issue with default configuration.

Comment: HI Nitin thanks for the quick response, I already use direct connect in my config file "exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['disable-infobars']
    }
  }"..Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code snippet in your configuration file & re run it.

jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
};

Comment: Hi Ram, i already mentioned  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000000,
    showColors: true

  } in my config file. Still getting the same error